# Cucumber js in visual studio 2013

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, specflow, cucumberjs

Is there a project with similar goals as [Specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) is to [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) in Visual Studio, but for [cucumberjs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js)?

I'm considering a unit testing / bdd framework for Visual Studio. Cucumberjs seems like the obvious choice as I am using Specflow to test the c#. However cucumberjs requires nodejs to be installed.

[Chutzpah](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) runs things like [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/), [qunit](https://qunitjs.com/) etc in Visual Studio. Is there a way to do the same for cucumberjs? Perhaps [nodejstools](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) for visualstudio with a mixture of something else?

<strike>There is a [Feature request: Cucumber-js support](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/discussions/434667) for Chutzpah, but it's work in progress.</strike>

(Chutzpah was moved to github, so the issue was lost)

[A new Chutzpah feature request on github for cucumber-js support](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/280)

There is an [interview with a cucumber core member](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/04/cucumberjs-bdd-biezemans) saying (below) which sounds promising:

> "Support for Cucumber.js is being added to popular IDEs like Jetbrains
>   Webstorm 8 and Visual Studio."

Comment: So, any update? How to do BDD in VS?

Comment: Hi @Toolkit it's not something I've looked at since in particular. Last time I did BDD in visual studio I used jasmine with chutzpah. However many things have changed with Visual Studio and JavaScript support namely nodejs tools and the task runner explorer (for gulp and grunt) so that may offer more insight.

Comment: so it seems like things are changing fast indeed. So I have an Angular SPA and it talks to Web API. What would be a appropriate set of testing tools? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Toolkit I'd probably recommend opening another question particular to Angular and WebAPI as that's treading into a different area. However chutzpah offers good integration specifically to unit tests. For a general automation approach I'd recommend looking at the Task Runner Explorer extension if you plan to use gulp or grunt.

Comment: honestly i am going nuts after two days of trying. I haven't managed to run ANYTHING, no cucumberjs, no jasmine, no bower or gulp. what on earth is going on?? it was long time since I met so much crap online.... Looks like a bunch of retards are writing some sporadic ideas, not tutorials

Comment: @Toolkit sorry to hear you're having trouble, because the question I opened is quite specific, if you are running into problems with tooling I'd recommend opening another question so that it gets attention, as this question was opened a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by using the [Visual Studio **Task Runner Explorer**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708). (You have to add it if you use VS 2013, with 2015 it's already included.)

This Extension is a task runner for Grunt and Gulp directly within Visual Studio 2013. It is now possible to define a Grunt task, like [this one](https://github.com/s9tpepper/grunt-cucumber-js) which runs your cucumberjs Features.

Comment: Thanks David. Good response for anyone who comes across this question, I must admit I forgot about :-) Visual Studio is a changed world, I too am using the Task Runner Explorer for gulp tasks, that's true it would be a great option these days for cucumberjs.

Answer (score 4):

As per David Leitner's reply, I've created a step-by-step guide to setting up cucumberjs in Visual Studio.

http://blogs.endjin.com/2015/10/step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-cucumberjs-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Thanks for sharing! SpecFlow highlights each step in feature files that are not mapped to a step definition. It's pretty handy when you get these feature files from the test team and you're tasked to match them up to definitions. I have a feeling that this (or any) solution does not provide us with such a mapping within the editor. Am I right on that? I know that when you run it you see which ones are not mapped, but that's not what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay - yes; that's correct. However, I'm slowly working on VS integration for a Cucumber. I've got a basic test runner working, and I'll publish the code and VSIX as soon as I get a spare minute; hopefully that will get us going and someone else can help build it out!